# Object property initially returns undefined, but upon redefinition returns expected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, javascript-objects

I’ve got a JavaScript object built like this:

```
var Dashboard = {
  form: {
    action: function(){
      return $('#upload_form').attr('action');
    }(),
    //snip (more functions)
  }
}
```

If I call (using Chrome 17 on WinXP) `Dashboard.form.action` in the Chrome console after the page loaded (I checked the script and the function is there) the result is `undefined` but, if I then redefine `Dashboard.form.action` using the same function:

```
Dashboard.form.action = function(){
  return $('#upload_form').attr('action');
}();
```

and subsequently call it, it works as expected!

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug or am I just overthinking it?

Comment: you create and initialize the object, but the form HTML is not loaded at this time... can this be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Re your comment below:

> actually what I want to do IS assigning the result to the action property...

In the question you said:

> If I call...`Dashboard.form.action`...

which makes it seem like you're expecting `action` to be a function (you don't "call" non-functions).

If you're expecting it to be a string (the "action" attribute value from `#upload_form`), then you don't need to use a function at all. But you **do** need to be sure that you're doing it **after** the `#upload_form` element already exists in the DOM.

To do that, either put your script below it in the markup ([anywhere below](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) it is fine; [just before or just after the closing `</body>` tag](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) works well), or wrap your script in a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) call.

So your code becomes either this if it's *after* the `#upload_form` in the markup:

```
var Dashboard = {

  form : {
      action : $('#upload_form').attr('action'),

      //snip (more functions)
  }
};
```

...or this if you want to use `ready` (anything else *using* `Dashboard` will have to wait until `ready` as well):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var Dashboard = {

      form : {
          action : $('#upload_form').attr('action'),

          //snip (more functions)
      }
    };
});
```

Note that in the second case, `Dashboard` will no longer be a global variable. That's a **good thing**, but if you need it to be global for some reason, you can export it:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var Dashboard = {

      form : {
          action : $('#upload_form').attr('action'),

          //snip (more functions)
      }
    };

    // Export the global
    window.Dashboard = Dashboard;
});
```

Just make sure nothing tries to use `Dashboard` before `ready` has fired.

---

**Original answer**:

You have an extra pair of `()` on that:

```
action: function(){return $('#upload_form').attr('action');}()
//                                              here -------^^
```

By putting them there, you **call** the function immediately, and assign the *result* of calling it to the `action` property. You just want to assign the function *itself* to the property, so don't put the `()` at the end to call it:

```
action: function(){return $('#upload_form').attr('action');}
```

This is for exactly the same reason you wouldn't use `()` here (let's assume you have a function called `foo`) if you want `f` to refer to `foo`:

```
var f = foo;
```

If you said

```
var f = foo();
```

...you'd be *calling* `foo`, not referring to it.

Comment: actually what I want to do IS assigning the result to the action property, I just can't figure out why it doesn't do it.

Comment: @OverLex: Ah, okay. Then you don't need a function at all (that and your saying "call" confused me). See the updated answer. :-)